# Remove Trailing Slash (/) in Makefile

Tags: string, variables, makefile, gnu-make

So in a makefile, if you want to get the directory just above you, you can do:

```
UP_ONE_DIR := $(subst $(notdir $(CURDIR)),,$(CURDIR))
```

The problem is, it ends with an '/' ending slash. Is there a pattern to remove this slash from the UP_ONE_DIR variable?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great idea to use `subst` because it can match multiple identical strings, for example if your path was `/foo/bar/foo/bar` or whatever.  You can use:

```
UP_ONE_DIR := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(CURDIR)))
```